# JSON to Core Data Pre Populating additional entities

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I have managed to pre-populate a core data model consisting of one entity with many attributes through a JSON file.

I then added a second entity, and came across problems in pre populating this entity using the same JSON file, So i thought i would create another JSON file to pre-populate the second entity, But this didnt seem to work.

The code below is what ive tried to use:

```
    //Below is the code for the first entity

    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Exercises" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* Exercises = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Imported Exercises: %@", Exercises);

    [Exercises enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        Exercise *exercise = [NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise"
                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
        exercise.tag = [obj objectForKey:@"tag"];
        exercise.name = [obj objectForKey:@"name"];
        exercise.type = [obj objectForKey:@"type"];    
       NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];







//Below is the code for the second Entity


    dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Weights" ofType:@"json"];



    //Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
    NSArray* Weights = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Imported Weights: %@", Weights);

    [Weights enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        Weight *weight = [NSEntityDescription
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Weight"
                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
        weight.weight = [obj objectForKey:@"weightEntry"];

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

Would be grateful for any help. Thank You

Comment: In what way did it not seem to work? What part failed? What happened that you did not expect to happen?

Comment: What was the problem? What happened when you tried to use the code posted? (aside: it's also unusual to save after every single insert, but I guess you're debugging?)

Comment: edited the error received into the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa provides a method that makes this much, much simpler. Thanks to key-value coding there’s a method in NSObject that reduces the above to a single line

```
[myObj setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:jsonDict];
```

This will run through key/value pairs in jsonDict and set the same key/value pairs on myObj